# De kie venas la vorto "Barato" por angle India?

Tags: etymology

Ĉiu vorto havas iun originon — iu iam elektis ĝin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laŭ vikipedio, ĝi venas de sanskrita nomo por la lando *Bhārata Gaṇarājya*, kiu siavice venas de imperiestro Bharata Chakravartin.